# Hide all class implementations (.m) files in Xcode

Tags: xcode4, project-navigator

Is there a way to hide all .m files in the project navigator of an Xcode workspace? I can always get to them through their headers, so I would like not to have to look at both header and implementation in the project navigator.

Comment: I don't think so. I think the best you could do is put your implementation files into a different group (folder) and not expand it.

Comment: To get halfway where you want to be type ".h" into the filter field (at the very bottom of the navigator). Hides ".m" (and pretty much everything else but ".h" files)